# In docker, what are advantages and disadvantages between 1 dedicated server running a single web server VS multiple web container in it

Tags: docker

I have a web application, db is in RDS and I'm thinking of using docker. What's the advantages/disadvantages between just using 1 web server running in EC2 instance **VERSUS** an EC2 instances running as a docker node with multiple web server containers. Will the docker scenario handle more requests? I'm thinking that docker scenario just makes it complicated since both scenarios are limited to hardware.

Comment: Docker (and containerization in general) is only needed _at scale_: When we talk about "scale": imagine running a website or webservice that handles millions of requests in a day with varying demand-levels: the website would be spread-out over multiple containers over multiple VMs - as demand reduces or VM host computers need to reboot you can move and change the quantity (and cost) of the docker containers. If you're working on a more modest web project that doesn't need to scale like that then using Docker is overkill and likely just a distraction.

Comment: Yes let's talk about "scale" and let's say we have millions of requests. We have multiple VMs running and let's pick 1 VM and compare it's performance on handling requests. A VM running a web server versus a VM with multiple web server docker containers, which is better?

Comment: In raw performance terms then the VM running a single web-server will be better, but the _business costs_ in time spent on manual server administration and deployment justify the use of containers because they save on those costs. I note that web-server request-handling limits aren't usually the main problems at scale where the backend databases become more of a bottleneck.

Comment: If performance is your key concern, then at a scale where you'll need multiple hosts,  cloud host vs. private VM vs. Docker is going to be a pretty negligible difference, probably less than the difference you'll see from putting a load balancer in front of it, and almost immeasurable compared to your per-request database latency.  Deploy-time and operational concerns are more interesting.